# Command line arguments in C# application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF C# application, to which I have to pass command line argument. The argument is actually a URL, which I have to then use in my application?

How are these command line arguments passed in WPF C#, so that the application can pickup the url during launch?

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972153(v=vs.90).aspx or google for WPF command line arguments

Comment: FWIW, Googling for "wpf command line arguments", the top 4 links were all to stackoverflow, including this one, that's how I landed here.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In your App.xaml.cs

```
class App : Application
{
    //Add this method override
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.Args is the string[] of command line arguments
    }
}
```

Comment: So, that means I'll have to do this in App.xaml and not in `MainWindow.xaml` etc. Is it?

Comment: If use in MainWindow.xaml.cs directly, then as suggested by others, Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

Comment: Is there some way to pass and check the command line arguments for my application from within Visual Studio, and not trying to lauch the application from outside?

Answer (score 33):

It has been mentioned by linquize above, but I think it is worth an answer of its own, as it is so simple...

You can just use:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

That works anywhere in the application, not just in App.xaml.cs

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments like "no-wpf" C# applications through comman line.
The difference is the application entry point. In WPF is App.xaml.cs. So, you have in this file you can pick arguments in this way:

```
class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.Args represent string[] of no-wpf C# applications
    }
}
```